Want to run a simulation on Omnet++ 6.0 for openDSME
I'm trying building the omnet++ 6.0 in order to run simulaiton for my research work for openDSME, but keeps getting the build error wwhich is kind of "use of deleted function" and so on. I would really appreciate any kind of help in order to make this build run to get my simulations running. I need it for my research work.
I have already followed the steps mentioned on openDSME.org website but everytime keeps getting the different build error with every other versions of inet and inet-dsme.
I tried running omnet++ 6.0 and omnet++ 5.7 with inet version of 4.3 and older versions of it in order to run simulation for OpenDSME to imitate DSME(IEEE 802.15.4). But keeps getting the build error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

For me, OpenDSME's master branch builds with omnetpp-5.4.2.

I tried with this version too but while using this version I got osg-earth related issue while running the "make" command.

Disabling osg and osg-earth in the configure.user file might solve this issue.
